# PHP-CGI.exe crash on IIS

Tags: php, windows, iis, sugarcrm, php-5.3

I'm running multiple SugarCRM sites on IIS 6.1 on a Windows 2008 environment. Databases are housed on a SQL 2008 R2 Server. We are running PHP 5.3.26 with Fast-CGI enabled. Wincache 1.3.4.0 is also enabled.

It appears that `php-cgi.exe` is crashing when a site is under heavy load,(20 + users) I managed to debug a crashed instance of `php-cgi.exe` and here's what I found -

`In php  cgi__PID__17080__Date__03_15_2015__Time_01_14_04PM__478__Second_Chance_Exception_C0000005.dmp the assembly instruction at kernel32!InterlockedIncrement+9 in C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll from Microsoft Corporation has caused an access violation exception (0xC0000005) when trying to write to memory location 0x00000001 on thread 0`

```
Thread report
Thread 0 - System ID 15852
Entry point   php_cgi+656a 
Create time   15/03/2015 10:02:43 
Time spent in user mode   0 Days 00:00:25.031 
Time spent in kernel mode   0 Days 00:00:40.406 
This thread is not fully resolved and may or may not be a problem.     
Further analysis of these threads may be required.
Function kernel32!InterlockedIncrement+9 
php_wincache!get_module+c592 
php5!php_pdo_stmt_delref+efb6
```

I am not sure what the above debug means. Can anyone advise what the error means and how I can prevent it from happening?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

PHP 5.3 is no longer supported.  And, with that, WinCache on PHP 5.3 is also no longer supported. However, the last build of WinCache for PHP 5.3 was 1.3.6.3, available [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wincache/files/development/wincache-1.3.6.3-dev-5.3-nts-vc9-x86.exe/download).  It contains several performance and stability improvements.

If you move to PHP 5.4, you can pick up more recent builds of WinCache that are even more stable and have new features such as function rerouting, and reduced dependence on the System Page File.